# Do I downgrade my JDK or upgrade my gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I am currently using Gradle 3.0, which supports JDK 9. I tried to download JDK 9 from Oracle's official website but you need an account for the archived versions (they require a company name and a work phone, none of which I can provide). My version of JDK is 15.0.1. As far as I know, the latest version of Gradle supports it. However, I'm not sure how to update Gradle in my workspace. Would updating it cause any errors since it's a huge gap between the versions?

For reference, the older version of Gradle came with the mod developer kit of the forge. I am currently working on the 1.8.9 version of Minecraft. I am using IntelliJ, not Eclipse. I apologize if I didn't structure my question properly.

Comment: Have you tried OpenJDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA has JDK downloader that offers multiple JDK versions/vendors. You can use JDK 1.8 for Gradle 3.0 or JDK 11 for Gradle 5.0+:

[image: Download JDK]

Comment: This worked as far as the JDK version goes, but I still can't get Gradle working properly. When I run setupDecompWorkspace, it doesn't generate GradleStart and/or GradleStartServer. I switched the JDK version to Amazon Corretto (1.8) and I'm using .main of my project as many answers suggest. Do you have any idea why that could be happening? Should I provide anything?

Comment: Share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Just Install sdkman.io
Then upgrading the Gradle/maven/jdk and many  other JVM project is as easy as running a command.
You can also switch between versions in a very convenient way.